# Show where a man in a tavern transforms into a werewolf like thing thrοugh magic I think and he fights outside the tavern with someone

Tags: story-identification

I’ve been looking for a long time for that show. In it a man in a tavern transforms into a werewolf like thing through magic I think and he fights outside the tavern with someone?

Comment: Seems a little vague. Can you elaborate on the man, the setting, the tavern, the plot, anything?

Comment: Its a cartoon or an anime. The fight is outside the tavern on a green grass field at day. The "werewolf" destroys a table before the fight and everyone in there is scared. The show was similar to dragon hunters

Answer (score 2):

I found that show randomly on netflix lol. It s called Wakfu. I was a little of with that werewolf thing haha Thank you!

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons in about 48 hours.